# Vuejs2 - Not able to apply property values from data object for the dynamically added table rows

Tags: vuejs2

I want to append dynamic rows to the table. Iam able to add dynamic rows but the property values defined inside the data object and css style not applied for those newly added rows. 1st row of the table(already defined one) shows the property value and its css also working fine

[image]

billing.vue

```
<template>
<b-card  id="showBill"> 
<div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" id="tbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Charges</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><select class="form-control input-sm form-control3"> <option v-for="option in chargesOpt" v-bind:value="option.value" :key="option.value"> {{ option.text }} </option></select></td>
            <td><input type="text" class=" form-control input-sm  form-control3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
         <tr class="table-secondary">
        <th>Total Amount</th>
        <th style="text-align:right;">0.00</th>
         </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="addRow">Add</button>
</div>
 </b-card>
</template>

<script>

export default {
   data () {
    return {
     chargesOpt:[
        { value: '', text: 'Select'},
        { value: '1', text: 'Maintanence'},
        { value: '2', text: 'Extra'}
    ]   
   }
  },
  methods:{
     addRow()
      {
        var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length-1;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = cell1.innerHTML +'<select class="form-control input-sm form-control3"> <option v-for="option in chargesOpt" v-bind:value="option.value" :key="option.value"> {{ option.text }} </option></select>';
        cell2.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML +'<input type="text" class=" form-control input-sm form-control3"/>';
      }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>

@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
.is-danger{
  color:  RED;
}
.form-control{display:block;padding:6px 12px;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#555;background-color:#fff;background-image:none;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);transition:border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out
}
.input-sm{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: #616161;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  resize: none;
}
.input-sm {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 35px;
}
.form-control3 {   /* For Vacancy List Table Input Fields */
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-color: transparent!important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-shadow: none !important;
 }       
.form-control3:focus {
    border: 1px solid #03a9f4 !important;
    background: #fff !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.form-control3{
    height: 30px;
}
 .form-control3,{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}       
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<tr v-for="charge in charges">
    <td>
        <select class="form-control input-sm form-control3" v-model="charge.opt">
            <option v-for="option in chargesOpt" v-bind:value="option.value" :key="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class=" form-control input-sm  form-control3" v-model="charge.value">
    </td>
</tr>
```

...

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            chargesOpt: [
                {value: '', text: 'Select'},
                {value: '1', text: 'Maintanence'},
                {value: '2', text: 'Extra'}
            ],
            charges: []
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.addRow();
    },

    methods: {
        addRow() {
            this.charges.push({
                value: '',
                opt: ''
            });
        }
    }
}
```

By using `v-for` on the table row and pushing a new object on to the `charges` array, vue will take care of creating the new row for you.

Comment: It's working. But in the amount field Iam able to only one character at a time. If I enter one number it loses it focus, and then I added the next character again it loses it's focus

Comment: Thnanks@Ross Wilson. I found the cause

Comment: @Ashwini What was the cause?

Comment: " <input type="text" class=" form-control input-sm  form-control3" v-model=" _**charge.value**_ ">". I added one more key called " **Amt** " and used it as "charge.Amt"  instead of "charge.value." I thought it considered "value" as a key of an array